# Creating dynamic elements with jQuery separately in different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery in order to create dinamically input forms. I made an example of my code (this example doesn't creates input forms but it works exacly as my script, and it reproduce the same error) that you can play in order to understand better what I mean.

The problem is that if I press "Add" of the first div "event", my jQuery produces the skulls with numbers starting from 1.
After that I press "Add" of the second div "event", but the numbers starts not from 1, but from the last number of the first div "event".

Change the class "event" is not possible. In this example there are 2 div but they could be 3-4-5 or more, all with the class "event".

What can I do in order to start both the "event" from 1?

```js
var i = 1;

$('.plus').click(function(e) {

  var $numberDiv = $('<span>' + i + '</span>').addClass('numberDiv');
  var $clear = $('<div />').addClass('clear');
  var $event = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.event');

  $event.find('.participantContainer').append($numberDiv);

  i++;
})

$('.minus').click(function(e) {
  var $numberDiv = $('<span>'> + i + '</span>').addClass('numberDiv');
  var $clear = $('<div />').addClass('clear');
  var $event = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.event');

  $event.find('.numberDiv:last').remove();

  i--;
})

$('.reset').click(function() {
 i = 1;
  $('.numberDiv').each(function() {
   $(this).remove();
  })
})
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

button {
    background: none;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.plus,
.minus,
.reset {
  height: 33px;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 2px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

.plus {
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 56px;
}

.plus:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

.minus:hover {
  background-color:red;
}

.minus {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 95px;
}

.reset {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 95px;
}

.reset:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.numberDiv {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.numberDiv:before {
  content:'☠';
  font-size: 30px;
}

.participantContainer {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event">
  <button class="plus">Add</button>
  <button class="minus">Remove</button>
  <div class="participantContainer"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="event">
  <button class="plus">Add</button>
  <button class="minus">Remove</button>
  <div class="participantContainer"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<button class="reset">Reset</button>
```

The main reason is of course that I'm learning and I don't have a lot of experience with jQuery.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: jQuery is a really poor choice for creating dynamic UIs. I'd suggest you try learning React or Elm instead..

Comment: As mentioned from user xs0 is [reactjs](https://reactjs.org/) a good choice!

Comment: Thank you for the answers! I understand that there some better solutions instead of jQuery... but what if I have to use it anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the count of existing skulls, and have your reset, just delete them. You could skip the counter altogether.

`var currentCount = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.event').find('.participantContainer').children('span').length;`

Uses the [`length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/) property to get the current count. Then increment it by one.

```js
$('.plus').click(function(e) {
  var currentCount = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.event').find('.participantContainer').children('span').length;
 
  var $numberDiv = $('<span>' + (currentCount+1) + '</span>').addClass('numberDiv');
  var $clear = $('<div />').addClass('clear');
  var $event = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.event');

  $event.find('.participantContainer').append($numberDiv);
})

$('.minus').click(function(e) {

  var $event = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.event');
  $event.find('.numberDiv:last').remove();
})

$('.reset').click(function() {
  $('.numberDiv').each(function() {
   $(this).remove();
  })
})
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

button {
    background: none;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.plus,
.minus,
.reset {
  height: 33px;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 2px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

.plus {
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 56px;
}

.plus:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

.minus:hover {
  background-color:red;
}

.minus {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 95px;
}

.reset {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 95px;
}

.reset:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.numberDiv {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.numberDiv:before {
  content:'☠';
  font-size: 30px;
}

.participantContainer {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event">
  <button class="plus">Add</button>
  <button class="minus">Remove</button>
  <div class="participantContainer"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="event">
  <button class="plus">Add</button>
  <button class="minus">Remove</button>
  <div class="participantContainer"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<button class="reset">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just change your variable i to be an array and target that on the plus and minus like so

```
var i = [];

$('.plus').click(function(e) {

  var index = $('.plus').index(this);
  i[index] = typeof i[index] === 'undefined' ? 1 : i[index] + 1;

  var $numberDiv = $('<span>' + i[index]  + '</span>').addClass('numberDiv');
  var $clear = $('<div />').addClass('clear');
  var $event = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.event');

  $event.find('.participantContainer').append($numberDiv);

})

$('.minus').click(function(e) {
  var index = $('.minus').index(this);
  i[index] = typeof i[index] === 'undefined' ? 1 : i[index] - 1;
  var $numberDiv = $('<span>'> + i[index]  + '</span>').addClass('numberDiv');
  var $clear = $('<div />').addClass('clear');
  var $event = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.event');

  $event.find('.numberDiv:last').remove();
})

$('.reset').click(function() {
    i = [];
  $('.numberDiv').each(function() {
    $(this).remove();
  })
})
```